# React setState() needs 2 clicks to update UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React. My question may be common in React developers and there are many same questions but I still don't know how to resolve that. I must still click twice to update UI state. The first click just calls event handler but not update counter variable in state. Even I used the callback form of setState() like the following:

```js
this.setState({ hasButtonBeenClicked: true }, () => {console.log("Clicked")});
```

the console.log("Clicked") was not reached in first click as well!

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Summary } from "./Summary";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
let names = ["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"]
function reverseNames() {
    names.reverse();
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
function promoteName(name) {
    names = [name, ...names.filter(val => val !== name)];
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }
    incrementCounter = (increment) => this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + increment});
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-sm table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Letters</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {names.map((name, index) =>
                        <tr key={name}>
                            <Summary index={index} name={name}
                                reverseCallback={() => reverseNames()}
                                promoteCallback={() => promoteName(name)}
                                counter={this.state.counter}
                                incrementCallback={this.incrementCounter}
                            />
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }

}
```

**Summary Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SimpleButton } from "./SimpleButton";

export class Summary extends Component {
    render() {
        const props = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <td>{props.index + 1} </td>
                <td>{props.name} </td>
                <td>{props.name.length} </td>
                <td>
                    <SimpleButton
                        className="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1"
                        callback={() => props.reverseCallback()}
                        text={`Reverse (${props.name})`}
                        {...this.props}
                    />
                </td>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

**SimpleButton**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
export class SimpleButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasButtonBeenClicked: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.props.incrementCallback(3);
        this.setState({ hasButtonBeenClicked: true });
        this.props.callback();
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                className={this.props.className}
                disabled={this.props.disabled === "true"
                    || this.props.disabled === true}>
                { this.props.text} { this.props.counter}
                { this.state.hasButtonBeenClicked &&
                    <div>Button Clicked!</div>
                }
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I cloned your shared code https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-allen-f9zs6 it seems to be working fine, what exactly are you trying to achieve here, with all the buttons sharing same counter

Comment: Yes, the code you posted in codesandbox.io working fine. That's weird. My local development not show the same result as yours. This is the screen I take after first click https://imgur.com/a/4uDnmRt. Note the button clicked not change label to "Reverse (A) 3 Button Clicked" as expected. My code is a snippet from a React book attempting to show features of React so purpose and and content may be not much meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by commenting out the line in App.js

```js
function reverseNames() {
    names.reverse();
    // ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

I thinks the line making app rerender before the actual state updated so I was behind the actual state 1 span. The first click is the initial state, the second click is the state after the first click .etc